# Preallocate memory for dynamic data structure

Tags: c++, c, memory, memory-management

I have a question/curiosity.
Let's say I want to implement a list, and for example I could basically use the cormen book approach. Where it is explained how to implement, insert, delete, key search etc.

However nothing is said for what the memory use is concerned. For example if I would like to insert an integer, in a list of integers. I could for example first create a node (I allocate memory there) insert the integer and then insert the node in the list. If I would like to delete an integers, once I know in which node is stored, I have to free the memory.

I was now wondering if instead it would be more convenient to preallocate memory to store, say, 10 nodes and keeping a pointer to a free node to be used. If the memory pool is full then I reallocate memory for 20 nodes, if the pool is the large I half the size of such pool (and so on and so forth). The pool is of course more complicated to manage since I'd need for example to handle possible memory fragmentation etc.

Does what I'm saying make any sense? Or is it no sense? I've read in a book, for game programming, that memory preallocation could improve performance, but I was wondering how.

Comment: This is less convenient than just allocating/freeing memory as needed, but much, much more efficient.Yes, this makes sense. After a certain point (when the algorithms are all fixed), nearly all optimization comes down to memory management (not just where it comes from, but how it is used as well, e.g. cache-aware optimization).

Comment: Memory pooling is a good thing to do if you have many allocations. It is just overhead if the there only few of them. Further, any contemporary memory allocation subsystem used pooling of some sort.

Comment: A common technique in optimizations is not to use lists but to use arrays.  Lists are not efficient data structures.  One could also use an array of nodes rather than a list.  See also B-Tree.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews, I wasn't try to point out if a list is efficient or not. I was trying to point out/understand that in context where one could do a bunch of insert/delete operations(and such operations are common to tree and graph as well) if it wouldn't be efficient to allocate/deallocate memory continuously.

Comment: Use an array of nodes.  Linked lists can be implemented using an array index instead of a pointer to the next node.  Using an array in this fashion means you don't need to keep performing memory allocations.

Comment: Note to the array advocates of a linked list: A custom allocator might just provide the same (A continuous block of memory, where pointers are just like indices)

Comment: Is it going to be an intrusive or non-intrusive list?

Comment: What you describe makes sense. Omitting the reallocating part (I would avoid) it has similarities to a std::deque (which of course is no list)

Comment: Is "cormen book" this [book](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Introduction_to_Algorithms)?

Comment: @chuck, Yes that's the book.

Answer (score 1):

This is both a simple and a complex question. If you operate within standard problems, you don't really need to worry about memory allocation. For example, preallocating memory for 10 nodes won't be efficient in any scale, and your performance problems might be elsewhere. However, if your program constantly allocates and deallocates hundreds or thousands of small objects per second, it could lead to memory fragmentation, and you might need to write your custom allocator.

Almost no standard containers don't have any methods to preallocate elements storage, except for `std::vector::reserve` function. All of them, however, allow to use custom allocators in constructors. Also, there's [placement new](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/dtors#placement-new) operator.

You could try to experiment with such things, they're fun to write, just don't use them in production if you absolutely don't have to.

Comment: Plain  wrong. *If you operate within standard problems, you don't really need to worry about memory allocation* - every allocation  is a disaster in  mt-environment.

Comment: @SergeyA  What is "mt-environment"?

Answer (score 0):

> I was now wondering if instead it would be more convenient to preallocate memory to store, say, 10 nodes and keeping a pointer to a free node to be used.

You basically are describing what a pool allocator usually does (I assume you are talking about nodes of constant size). So, the short answer to your question is: yes you would improve performance by using a pool allocator with a list container.

Memory allocators shipped with common compilers are quite good for general purpose allocation (i.e. for allocation of random size objects). However, when your need is to allocate objects of constant size, you should consider using a custom pool allocator. You can easily understand why a constant size objects allocator performs faster than the standard one.

You might write your own pool allocator, however it's not an easy task and you should better consider using an existing one, such as boost [pool_allocator](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_60_0/libs/pool/doc/html/boost/pool_allocator.html) or [fast_pool_allocator](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_60_0/libs/pool/doc/html/boost/fast_pool_allocator.html).